# How to design a datamodel with different data items and group them in one grid?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, viewmodel, datamodel

I'm new to Windows Store Apps although not new to .net Development in general. I'm trying to set up a concept for an app which should present tourism data to the user (e.g. sights, hotels, books and some more. I'm trying to achieve something like the Windows Store App, to put all the different data in a grid grouped by their type (sights, hotels, books, etc.).

In the Windows store each Item is from the same type (an app) which has the same properties. In my case the items will share some common properties (title, description, etc.) but each one will also have some properties on their own. Following is a excerpt from the data in xml-format (just for illustration purposes).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
    <Sights>
        <Sight Title="Windbergbahn" SubTitle="Deutschlands erste Gebirgsbahn" Country="Deutschland" Region="Sachsen" Town="Dresden">
            <Content>Die Windbergbahn wurde 1856 erbaut und ist damit Deutschlands erste Gebirgsbahn.</Content>
            <Images></Images>
        </Sight>
    </Sights>
    <Hotels>
        <Hotel Title="Hilton Dresden" SubTitle="Direkt an der Frauenkirche" Country="Deutschland" Region="Sachsen" Town="Dresden" Capacity="300" Classification="5">
            <Content>Das Hilton Hotel liegt direkt in der Altstadt nur wenige Meter von der Frauenkirche entfernt.</Content>
            <Images></Images>
        </Hotel>
    </Hotels>
    <Books>
        <Book Title="Das alte Dresden" SubTitle="Some subtitle" Author="Anton Author" ISBN="643787383333" Price="19.99" Currency="EUR">
            <Content>Das Buch zeigt Fotos der Jahrhundertwende des alten Dresden.</Content>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Items>
```

So how must I design my data model and/or view model to group them in one grid? Maybe I need some common data item with the common properties as parent and all the childs derive from them and add their special properties? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael